# Почему при архивировании tar с опциями --acls|--xattrs контрольная сумма файла разная?

Tags: linux, debian, tar, gzip, acl

В случае использования в виде

```
tar -cf - 123.png | gzip -n -c >png.tar.gz
tar -cf - 123.png | gzip -n -c >png2.tar.gz
```

контрольные суммы `md5sum` архивов совпадают. Если же я сохраняю расширенные атрибуты файла в архив соответствующими опциями

```
tar --acls --xattrs -cf - 123.png | gzip -n -c >png.tar.gz
tar --acls --xattrs -cf - 123.png | gzip -n -c >png2.tar.gz
```

то контрольные суммы архивов всегда разные. Почему так? Можно ли это обойти?

Comment: Наверное access time меняется

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52668432/4827341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такая красота получилась, которая считает сумму и параллельно создаёт архив на основе абсолютных путей из файла:

```
tar --xattrs --acls --posix --pax-option=exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f,delete=atime -cf - --files-from=123.txt 2>/dev/null | gzip -n -c | tee 123.tar.gz | md5sum
```